# populating text boxes using a drop down menu with database information

Tags: javascript, php, html

hello people I am currently pulling my hair out trying to figure out how to populate text boxes with the information in a database after the user has selected "date" for example from a dropdown menu.

My dropdown menu is currently being populated by the departure_date of a tour and I would like all of the other information connected to that date to be displayed into the text boxes on the page.

This is for a project I am working on and our current server does not support pdo unfortunately.

This is making my head spin and I cannot think about how I am supposed to accomplish this. Searching on the internet did not give me any useful information.

Here is my html code for the select box and text boxes.

```
<div>

  <label><strong>Search Tours</strong></label>
<form>
  <p>
    <select name="lst_tour">
      <option value="">Select a Tour:</option>
      <?php 

foreach ( $results as $option ) : ?>
      <option value="<?php
     
          echo $option->departure_date; ?>"><?php echo $option->departure_date; ?>    </option>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p><strong>List of Tour Details</strong></p>


        <input name="txt_tourname" type="text" id="txt_tourname" readonly="readonly"     value = <?php echo $ltour_name ?> />
      </label></td>

        <input name="txt_departuredate" type="text" id="txt_departuredate"  readonly="readonly" />
      </label>


        <input name="txt_tourdetails" type="text" id="txt_tourdetails"     readonly="readonly" />
      </label>
```

and here is my php connection code

```
     <?php
session_start();

        $server = "server";
        $schema = "schema";
        $uid = "name";
        $pwd = "pass";

    $tour_name =$_POST["txt_tourname"];
    $departure_date =$_POST["txt_departuredate"];
    $tour_details =$_POST["txt_tourdetails"];
    $no_of_volunteers =$_POST["txt_noofvolunteers"];


mysql_connect($server , $uid , $pwd) or die ("server not found");
mysql_select_db($schema) or die ("Database not found");

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM tour";
     $query = mysql_query($sql);
     while ( $results[] = mysql_fetch_object ( $query ) );
     array_pop ( $results );
?>
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: did you just liberally delete code from your html content? it looks like it's gone through a blender TT

Comment: yeah i made it easier for people to see to save time as it is very untidy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this question is asked and answered a lot and most of those who ask have a concept problem. I'll explain this in parts, and afterwards I'll post a clean rewrite of your code, including a javascript file for you to dive in and learn

- The idea behind what you are trying to do involves some sort of **behaviour** on the part of what looks most likely to be a static html page
- **Javascript** adds behaviour to your otherwise dead html, allowing you to trigger events and generate responses
- **Ajax** was born out of a collective necessity to be able to talk to the server while the user did not leave the page. It allows us to make requests behind the scene (*asynchronously*) and bring back info
- the power to combine **behaviour** with **asynchronous requests** is the base of today's rich internet applications (RIA for short?)

Ok, don't take that at face value, do some research on it and and you'll find out the potential. In the meantime I'll create a mockup of what it looks like you want and *I'll be back* with it as soon as I can. Be on the lookout for other answers, there is a lot of knowledgeable people around ^^

## edits

#### html form

```
<form method="somemethod" action="somescript.php">
  <select name="lst_tour" id="lst_tour">
    <option value="">Select a Tour:</option>
    <?php foreach ( $results as $option ) {
      ?><option value="<?php echo $option->departure_date; ?>"><?php echo $option->departure_date; ?></option><?php
    } ?></select>
  <!-- these will be "magically" populated, they conveniently have ids ^^ -->
  <input name="txt_tourname" type="text" id="txt_tourname" readonly="readonly" />
  <input name="txt_departuredate" type="text" id="txt_departuredate" readonly="readonly" />
  <input name="txt_tourdetails" type="text" id="txt_tourdetails" readonly="readonly" />
</form>
```

#### javascript

lot's of edits and rewrites. This is a noisy script with lots of `alerts` so please be patient and sequentially start removing alerts as you no longer need them. **Attention:** the select tag **has an id** that I use to find it and attach the event handler

```
(function(){
  var
    // the php script that's taking care of business
    url = 'http://path/to/handling/ajaxscript.php',
    select,
    // assume these are the ids of the fields to populate
    //  AND assume they are the keys of the array thats comming from the server
    inputs = ['txt_tourname','txt_departuredate','txt_tourdetails'],
    // the XMLHttpRequest, I'm not recycling it but, oh well
    xhr,
    // the onReadyStateChange handler function, it needs access to xhr
    xhrRSC,
    // event handler, called for <select>."onChange"
    onChooseDate,
    // response handler that will be executed once the xhrRSC deems it ready
    populateData,
    // convenient event handlers
    onLoad, onUnload;
  xhrRSC = function () {
    if (xhr && xhr.readyState !== 4) {return;}
    alert('the server response has completed. Now continue with the population');
    populateData(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
    xhr = null;
  };
  onChooseDate = function () {
    var date = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    alert('I have been changed. Did I select the right date: '+date
      +'. Now we send some info to the server');
    // AJAX: make xhr
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // AJAX: setup handler
    xhr.onreadystatechange = xhrRSC;
    // AJAX: open channel
    xhr.open('get',url+'?ajax=1&date='+date,true);
    // AJAX: send data (if method post)
    xhr.send(null);
    // if we had jQuery, we could condense all this into one line
    // $.post(url,{ajax:1,date:date},populateData,'json');
  };
  populateData = function (json) {
    // we have the content from the server. Now json decode it
    alert('json data => '+json.toSource());
    // foreach input id execute function
    inputs.forEach(function(v){
      // set the value of each input to the data sent by the server
      alert('setting input "'+v+'" to "'+json[v]+'"');
      document.getElementById(v).value = json[v];
    });
  };
  onLoad = function () {
    alert('page has loaded');
    // assume the <select> tag has an id of "lst_tour", just as it's name
    select = document.getElementById('lst_tour');
    // the "change" event is fired when the user changes the selected <option>
    select.addEventListener('change',onChooseDate,false);
  };
  onUnload = function () {
    select.removeEventListener('change',onChooseDate,false);
    select = null;
  };
  window.addEventListener('load',onLoad,false);
  window.addEventListener('unload',onUnload,false);
}());
```

#### ajax script, the php handler

```
<?php
// this file has $_GET populated with 'ajax' => '1' and 'date' => 'what the user chose'
if (!isset($_GET['ajax'])) die('this is not how its supposed to work');
// we must protect the output
ob_start();
// your initializers
// your logic: it should make the selection, then populate the array to be JSON encoded

$response = array(
  'txt_tourname' => $txt_tourname,
  'txt_departuredate' => $txt_departuredate,
  'txt_tourdetails' => $txt_tourdetails
);
// you may want to log this for debugging
// server output has been protected
ob_end_clean();
header('Content-Type: text/json');
echo json_encode($response);
// the client has what he wanted
exit;
```

There it is, it's not tested and it's a handfull but with careful review you will learn a LOT. Also read **Crockford** and take into consideration the benefits of using jQuery, that javascript could have been much less complicated, and more efficient with jQuery

Comment: Thanks for the info. is it possible in ajax to edit the results and update them into the database?

Comment: yes, you may do anything you want with this kind of stuff. The ajax requests are literal **requests** to the server. You may pass data to them and do as you wish with it. You can configure message boxes in case an error happens. possibilities. are. endless.

Comment: I forgot to add that the javascript is not tested. You can test it and give me some feedback if you like

Comment: i am getting no errors but the code also is not doing anything when i click in the dropdown box nothing is put into the text boxes at all is there something i am missing i can repost me code if you need. any help would be great thanks

Comment: did you just copy paste the javascript? if you did it's a bad idea. Try to understand what is being done, if you understand the code then you can debug it according to your own environment, let's remember that th js is kinda catered to the barebones html form I posted, and even that is not 100% sure to work. If you want, I can edit the script to add some debugging functions and some comments

Comment: I have retyped in the js code but it is still doing the same thing and have used various alerts but nothing seems to be able to fix it :S

Comment: I made the edits. You must be very carefull to not forget to review the code. Then test it, and if there are any errors, post them back. Also, this script has very little error checking, it **assumes** your browser has `addEventListener`, `JSON`, `XMLHttpRequest`. Let's cross our fingers